# psycopg2 cannot execute multiple queries

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm having issues with executing multiple queries on my psql db using psycopg2. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

def CreateUser(user, mySchema):

    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='root' password='somePassword' host='localhost'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""create user %s""" % (user)) 
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    CreateSchema(user, mySchema)


def CreateSchema(user, mySchema):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='root' password='somePassword' host='localhost'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""create schema %s authorization %s """ % (user,mySchema))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

def FetchUserInput():
    userInput = raw_input("UserName")
    mySchema = raw_input("SchemaName")
    CreateUser(userInput, mySchema)


FetchUserInput()
```

In this case, the second query fails with an error that the user created previously does not exist! 
If I only execute the CreateUser function, it works fine. 
If I execute it manually within psql, it works fine.

As If the first commit isnt executed on the database when I open up a second connection within the CreateSchema function, which makes no sense.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've just inverted the 2 parameters in the second query :

```
cur.execute("""CREATE SCHEMA %s AUTHORIZATION %s """ % (mySchema, user))
```

Some help from the doc:

> CREATE SCHEMA schema_name [ AUTHORIZATION user_name ] [ schema_element [ ... ] ]
>
> CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION user_name [ schema_element [ ... ] ]
>
> CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema_name [ AUTHORIZATION user_name ]
>
> CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS AUTHORIZATION user_name